# Insert form data into database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, razor

Is it possible to just iterate through the post results and insert them into the appropriate fields in a table? Instead of doing Request.Form["something"] for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

`Request.Form` is a `NameValueCollection`. This means you can refer to specific keys how you are already doing it: `Request.Form["something"]`,  or you can iterate through the items using a foreach loop

```
foreach (string value in Request.Form){
    // do stuff with value
    // save-to-database-function(value)
    // ...
}
```